# Ram USB storage device

Tags: usb, computers, ram, storage

I have been searching for a storage solution that can be written to an infinite amount of times, and RAM comes up every time. 
So is it possible to connect RAM to a controller and use it like a pendrive?(I realize that it would be volitle)

I've heard some people say that a necessity for such a project is a CPU is that true?

This has nothing to do with external RAM, I am not planning to use such a device as external RAM.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. You can write to anything an infinite number of times... whether you can read it back an infinite number of times is another matter. 2. You CAN NOT read back from ANYTHING an infinite number of times. Other than that... your question is vague... define "controller". And no, you don't need a CPU to write to memory.

Comment: And what does the question have to do with USB as mentioned in the title?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was talking a bout a memory controller. I just meant that normal flash memory has a limited of write cycles (Or so I thought) and RAM doesn't. Thanks for the reply! Oh and I meant that I want to build a device which acts like a pendrive but use RAM instead of flash, so basically a USB storage device

Comment: You are aware your RAM needs to be powered all the time, not to lose data.

Comment: Yes, [I need more words]

Comment: Perhaps you should describe the purpose of all of this... otherwise this is a non-question.

Comment: You could consider FRAM. It has very high endurance and fast read / write and is non-volatile

Comment: You must be thinking of 20 years ago. Today's USB flash drives can have millions of read/write cycles. Wear leveling is built into the internal controller. Use of the word 'infinite' is nonsensical. If your USB memory has issues 200 years from now, will you care? VTC.

Answer (score 2):

RAM chips have a limit to the number of successful writes and reads. They are just higher than Flash chips. And ram is just as likely as flash to die. And RAM does not have the storage capacity of flash.

Given that, and you knowing that it will be volatile, there is no reason you can't use RAM as a flash drive. You would need a custom controller that handles the USB to storage interface. Though I suspect it wouldn't be much different than a standard usb to flash controller, the concepts are the same. You'd be creating this from scratch though.

Keep in mind that the main benefit if RAM chips is speed, which you will not benefit from as usb and overhead will be your bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'll be looking in other directions because this is clearly too difficult.